# Trouble using Oracle SQL variable in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I'm trying to write a script to help assist with the numerous "What's happened to this actionlist" type calls, but i'm coming up against a brick wall doing some of the most simplest operations.

I'm trying to declare a variable and use it in the where clause of a query.  I've trimmed everything irrelevant out of the query, in an attempt to get this core functionality to work.

The id is usually an 18 digit number, but does occasionally contain alpha-numerics, hence why it is a varchar.  The column I'm trying to compare it to is an 18 byte varchar field.

```
declare
  id_to_check VARCHAR(18);  

begin
  id_to_check := '549576015500000109';

select 
  txn_timestamp, exception_type
from cut.event
where irn_id = id_to_check;

end;
```

Every time it throws an error:  'an INTO clause is expected in this select statement'.  I understand how INTO's work, i.e. if I wanted to assign the result of a select to the variable, but I don't understand how that would apply in this instance as I'm not assigning the result of the query to a variable?

The other frustrating thing is I'm actually following documentation on docs.oracle.com.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/overview.htm#LNPLS001.

I've also looked at various google results, but I can't figure out how to do a comparison with the variable without first selecting something into it, but as you can see, I can't select into because I only need it for comparison reasons?

Kind Regards,
Ian

Answer (score 3):

Raphaël Althaus's answer applies if you are doing something in PL/SQL, but I'm not sure that's actually what you want. It sounds like you want a plain SQL query, but you want to be able to pass it a value? Assuming you're running this in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer you have a few ways to declare and use a fixed value. (Similar methods will be available in other clients; PL/SQL developer seems to like both of these, at least in the command window, but not sure about Toad or anything else).

1) Using a [substitution variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#autoId19):

```
define id_to_check = 549576015500000109

select txn_timestamp, exception_type
from cut.event
where irn_id = '&id_to_check';
```

2) Using a [bind variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#autoId30):

```
variable id_to_check varchar2(18)

exec :id_to_check := '549576015500000109';

select txn_timestamp, exception_type
from cut.event
where irn_id = :id_to_check;
```

The `exec` is shorthand for a small anonymous PL/SQL block, but apart from step of assigning the value to the variable, it's plain SQL, so the query doesn't need to be wrapped in a `begin ... end`, and you don't have to worry about selecting `into` variables.

In either case you can have the ID value [passed as an argument](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#autoId24), or [ask for it as part of the script](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#autoId26), when the script it run. For example, you could write a `query.sql` script:

```
define id_to_check = &1

select txn_timestamp, exception_type
from cut.event
where irn_id = '&id_to_check';
```

... and run it with:

```
sqlplus -l -s <user>/<password> @query 549576015500000109
```

... or as:

```
accept id_to_check prompt 'Enter the ID to check: '

select txn_timestamp, exception_type
from cut.event
where irn_id = '&id_to_check';
```

... and have the user prompted to enter the ID at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not "Do you want to put the result into a variable".

In the "body" of an Oracle procedure, you just can't use a `SELECT` without an `INTO` clause.

(In fact you can have, but in a cursor).

so

```
declare
  id_to_check VARCHAR(18);
  event_timestamp cut.event.txn_timestamp%TYPE;
  event_exception cut.event.exception_type%TYPE;

begin
  id_to_check := '549576015500000109';

select 
  txn_timestamp, exception_type
  INTO event_timestamp, event_exception
from cut.event
where irn_id = id_to_check;

end;
```

Caution : if no result is found, this will raise a NO_DATA_FOUND exception.

You can manage it with

```
begin
  id_to_check := '549576015500000109';

  BEGIN
  select 
    txn_timestamp, exception_type
    INTO event_timestamp, event_exception
    from cut.event
    where irn_id = id_to_check;

   EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
   --...something
  END

end
```

Comment: Admittedly, I'm coming to Oracle from a Microsoft T-SQL background, so some of Oracle's 'features' are still new to me.

Comment: @user1774673 sure, my intention was not to be rude, it's just a fact ;)

Comment: Admittedly, I'm coming to Oracle from a Microsoft T-SQL background, so some of Oracle's 'features' are still new to me.

How would I create a variable with a fixed-value, for further use within my script, without somehow satisfying the INTO requirement?  I'm still writing my script but got sidetracked by this issue.

I don't need to dynamically assign any values into the variable - I am trying to create a script for our support team to easily obtain a lot of info in one place rather than querying multiple tables, and that ID is the key.

Comment: Raphael,

Many thanks for that, however having to do:

    declare
      id_to_check VARCHAR(18);
      event_timestamp cut.event.txn_timestamp%TYPE;
      event_exception cut.event.exception_type%TYPE;

would prove troublesome as I estimate I need to pull back about 30 columns of data.  using a view is out of the question as we are unable to edit all 80 databases we support without written consent of the customers, hence wanting to write it in a single query/script.

Comment: @user1774673 couldn't you create a view ?

Comment: I can't create a view as our support team are not able to create new tables or views on all 80 of our supported databases without written consent from each customer.

Comment: @user1774673 ok. What is not clear to me, is what kind of result you want :how  do you want to display the results ?

Comment: I want to return all txn_timestamps and exception_types in a grid where the irn_id matches the variable value.

Comment: @user1774673 in a grid ? You mean a web grid, with data coming from a Stored procedure ?

Answer (score 0):

Your real problem is NOT about using variable (you got that right), but about returning cursors from PL/SQL blocks.

You seem to believe that a bare select at the end of a procedure should somehow make it return the results or at least display them. While some databases work like that - Oracle does not. If you want any data to leave a block of any kind (like function or procedure), you have to pass them explicitly. Usually this is done by using an in parameter of a cursor ref type.

As you can see, the select without into would not make sense in Oracle. Even if you managed to make it work and select the data, you would not be able to access the results.